# Android ViewModel doesn't survive fragment change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I've been trying to share information between fragments using viewmodel's and livedata's.

But when I change from first fragment to another it seems that my viewmodel is reinitialized, making me lose all my previously stored data.

I get both times my viewmodel the same way in my fragments :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    interventionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InterventionsViewModel.class);

}
```

And this is how I replace my framgents in my activity (I guess the problem must come from the fragments lifecycles but I can't figure out where is the error :/)

```
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    String TAG = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

public void backstackFragment() {
    Log.d("Stack count", getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() + "");
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        finish();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    removeCurrentFragment();
}

private void removeCurrentFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment currentFrag = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (currentFrag != null) {
        transaction.remove(currentFrag);
    }
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

When I need a fragment I call `backStackFragment()` to remove current fragment then I call `showFragment(MyFragment.newInstance());`

The fragment are the ones generated by AndroidStudio

Thanks for your help,

Cordially,
Matthieu

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try binding to the activity instead of the current fragment.

```
interventionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(InterventionsViewModel.class);
```

Comment: In the observers too? (Btw what a fast answer :o)

Comment: Sure thing!! :)

Comment: Thank you it worked! You were literally too fast for stackoverflow I'll accept your answer when it'll allow me... How dumb from me binding the activity feels more logic... Again, thank you!

Comment: I appreciate it :)

Comment: How come you have to use an activity?  Isn't the whole point of a ViewModel that it survive destruction of elements, such as fragments?

Comment: @spiff : Yes you are right! But if you want to have a SharedViewModel then you need to pass the context of the activity.

Answer (score 4):

Since the [`ViewModelProviders` class is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders) the correct way is to use `ViewModelProvider` and let the ViewModel survive the fragments life-cycle by binding it to the activities life-cycle by using

```
requireActivity()
```

as documented by Google [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing):

```
model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

`call getActivity()` method in fragment which return activity

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should initialize your view model in `onActivityCreated` method instead of `onCreate` like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    interventionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InterventionsViewModel.class);

}
```

Its still weird, it keeps reload when fragment change too far (2 or more steps) but it works though, I prefer using `androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader`, that loader keeps your data very well.

Comment: No need to use onActivityCreated in plave of onViewCreated, and loaders are deprecated.

Comment: None answer above is working with me, so i come up with this... Could you suggest the better answer, please ?